# Toggle status bar text color between black and white

Tags: android, statusbar

**The app starts with status bar color:**

*Background white, the text is black.*

When entering modal pop up screen, status bar changes to back, with white text:

```
window?.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
```

**Works!**

Next, on modal popup screen dismiss, I would like the status bar to go back to normal:

*background white, and black text*

**with no luck.**

What did I try?
This:

```
window?.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK); // This really does work
activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = // Not sure what should be the value
```

Status bar background does change, but not text.
Not sure what **systemUiVisibility** value should be.

Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View 
But didn't find anything suitable, tried

*SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN,
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE*

**Still no luck.**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the `decorView`'s `systemUiVisibility` to have the following flag turned on `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`.

In your case

```
activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```